# float right without text coming up in line or overlapping

Tags: html, css

I have used `float: right;` to float a whole paragraph to the right - I am highlighting bits of text with a background & border. My problem is that the text below then moves up and wraps to the left of the object (paragraph) that I've floated right. `position: absoloute; right:0px;` doesn't work as it overlaps.

So my question is, how do I float it right, but ensure the text below stays below?

CSS:

```
.fcsi {
    background: #1E73BE;
    padding:20px;
    color: white;
    border: 2px solid #1E73BE;
    border-radius: 25px;
    float: right;
}
```

I've just used a simple div class in HTML around the text.

```
<div class="fcsi">
TEXT
</div>
```

Any help much appreciated on this.

After this, I am looking at including an image inside the background & border, aligned top-right or bottom-right. I think I cannot do this with CSS though and need to re-enter the image with HTML each time?

Comment: Please create a fiddle (jsfiddle.net) with your original code, so we can understand better and give a most accurate answer ;)

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know what this means and got a little lost on jsfiddle.net.

Comment: Thanks - OK, I am a real amateur at this so I don't know how to put the javascript in, but I've put the html and css in for this: http://jsfiddle.net/Le4jLdo9/

Comment: I'll try and work out the javascript as that output looks fine, but isn't what I'm actually getting. This may take me some time..

Comment: I've pasted in all the CSS I am using but it doesn't seem to have changed the visual in jsfiddle -  http://jsfiddle.net/Le4jLdo9/1/

Comment: In your website it appears different? Maybe a javascript forcing css...

Comment: Appreciate your time but I'm pretty lost and the trick below seems to be working. I might come back to this when I am more knowledgable and see if there is a 'proper' way. For now, adding the extra div will do the job. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below the floated paragraph you could add:

```
<div style="clear:both;height:1px"></div>
```

Comment: This seems to work thank you! If thats the only (and cleanest) way then I'll use that in all instances. I am surprised there isn't a way on inputting into the CSS to say 'align right but still require the entire row and let nothing come up in the same row'.